# Loading third party library: not found

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to include a third party library into my Symfony 2 project as explained [here](http://www.kiwwito.com/article/add-third-party-libraries-to-symfony-2). However, I keep getting the error message `Fatal error: Class 'Sprain_Images' not found in /src/MyProject/MyBundle/Controller/BackendController.php on line 267`.

Here is what I did:

I put a third party class into the src folder (not directly in vendors because this class is not available to be loaded by deps).

```
#Directory structure
-src
  -MyProject
  -vendor
     -sprain
       -lib
         -Images
           -src
           Images.php
```

Then I created the class to be used:

```
 # /src/vendor/sprain/lib/Images/Images.php
 require_once __DIR__.'/src/class.Images.php';
 class Sprain_Images extends Images {
 }
```

I also registered the prefix in autoload.php:

```
# /app/autoload.php
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
  'Twig_Extensions_' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig-extensions/lib',
  'Twig_'            => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig/lib',
  'Sprain_'          => __DIR__.'/../src/vendor/sprain/lib',
));
```

And eventually I called the class in my controller:

```
# /src/MyProject/MyBundle/Controller/BackendController.php
$image = new \Sprain_Images();
```

However the class is not being found. Where did I make the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Sprain_Images` should be in `src/vendor/sprain/lib/Sprain/Images.php`.

You can read more about the PSR-0 standard : https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md#underscores-in-namespaces-and-class-names

Comment: Should have known that, definitely was blind to the obvious. Thanks!

Comment: This answer gave me a little hint for my starting point, I added another answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify your composer.json file for the autoload value:

http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

```
//composer.json in your symfony 2.1 project
"autoload": {
     "psr-0": { 
         "": "src/", 
         "YourLibrary": "src/location/of/lib"
     }
},
```

And then in your controller for example:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use YourLibrary\FolderName\ClassName.php;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
   $lib = new ClassName();
   $lib->getName();

   return array('name' => $name);
}

}
```